# How to handle alt-key events on a form with c#?

Tags: c#, forms

I have the following code that has worked twice and then quit working altogether after I modified the underlying form controls. I can't see what's wrong with the code or why changing the underlying controls would matter to the form.

What do I have to do to get ProcessCmdKey to work reliably?

```
    namespace xyz
    {
        public partial class DaysNHours : Form
        {
            public DaysNHours()
            {
                this.KeyPreview = true;

                InitializeComponent();
            }

            // Detect alt-key presses directed to checkboxes and time boxes

            protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
            {
                if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.F))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("What the Ctrl+f?");
                    return true;
                }
                return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly did you change?

Comment: You copy/pasted my answer perfectly.  You were however supposed to change it, Keys.Control is not going to recognize an Alt key.

Comment: Jaycee - I wish it did but when I press any alt combination, I get a beep. My form has quite a few alt key combinations setup on it.

Comment: Hans- I wasn't sure I had the gist of what you intended right which is why I started with just what I interpreted from your post. Once I got this bit working, I had intended on implementing the code I need to get the form working. First thing though is to get *any* key to go through my processcmdkey module. Right now, the module is completely bypassed. I have the distinct feeling I've set something in Visual Studio that is disabling alt key functionality but have no idea what it would be.